# flask.cli.NoAppException: Failed to find application in module?

Tags: python, flask

I am following the tutorial on http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/factory/
I am just starting and it seemed simple but when I had the app running, I am just wondering why it throws this error:

> flask.cli.NoAppException: Failed to find application in module
>   "flaskr".  Are you sure it contains a Flask application?  Maybe you
>   wrapped it in a WSGI middleware or you are using a factory function.

I believe I have followed the steps perfectly, why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try going back to the `flask-tutorial/` directory, then run  `$ flask run` command.

Importing `flaskr` must be done from the `flask-tutorial/` directory (which contains flaskr).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with python not able to find the app in the path.

Add this code and test:

`import sys`

`print(sys.path)`

Check if the printed path array has containing folder's path. If not, for a quick fix use 
`sys.path.append('./')`

Otherwise you will have to investigate where you are messing with the python path.